# How to have VB.Net close a set of forms by tag value

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am creating and showing a set of forms by clicking on button1. I then need to click on button2 to close all of these forms.

by event button1_Click:

```
Dim frm As New myfrm()

frm.Tag = "temptag"

frm.TopLevel = False

controls.add(frm)
```

by event button2_Click:

close any form where `tag = "temptag"`

How to create code that will achieve that?

Comment: See my updated code bellow. I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do what you want without using tags:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ChildNumber As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frm As New Form1
        ChildNumber += 1
        frm.Text = "Child Form " & ChildNumber
        frm.Show()
        frm.TopLevel = False
        Me.Controls.Add(frm)
        frm.Tag = "temptag"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim count As Integer = Me.Controls.Count
        For i As Integer = Me.Controls.Count - 1 to 0 Step -1
            Dim ctrl As Control
            ctrl = Me.Controls(i)
            If ctrl.Tag = "temptag" Then
                DirectCast(ctrl, Form1).Dispose()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That Do While loop doesn't win any prizes for clarity.  Just use For i As Integer = Me.Controls.Count-1 To 0 Step -1.  Use Dispose() instead of Close().

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For x As Integer = Me.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim Ctrl As Control = Me.Controls(x)
        Try
            If Ctrl.Tag = "temptag" Then
                Ctrl.Dispose()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next

End Sub
```

Edit:

Updated the for loop to step backwards through the control collection (thereby not missing any controls - thanks @Tarik), and changed `.Close` to `.Dispose` as per @Hans Passant advise to Tarik

Comment: You cannot add the created forms in the Controls collection.

Comment: @Tarik, if you set the form's `Toplevel = false` you can add the form to another form's control collection

Comment: Did you test your code? I attempted to remove items within a for each and missed some forms which did not close. This is because we are removing items while looping using an iterator.

Comment: here my code and ok, to create new form


Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click

Dim frm As New myform()

frm.Tag = "temptag"

frm.TopLevel = False

Controls.Add(frm)

end sub


and how to close thats form, with form.tag = "temptag" ???
any idea ??

Comment: @Tarik, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't get a chance to test it (which I should of mentioned), but I've edited my post to handle the fact it's removing controls while looping with the iterator

Comment: @user2910974 I've updated the code so all you have to do is copy my code and change the button to your button